# How to take an input from HTML using JS/Jquery and query elasticsearch

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch

I have a simple HTML page with a Text Field and Button

Domain Number:

This text box will ask the user for a Domain number. Once the user enters the domain number, I would like to take that value and query Elasticsearch as follows

```
/GET/domainnumber/_search
{
"query" : {
   "match": {
     "Domain Number":"201710283fc113afa731459285b55d94bb8ddf02"
         }
       }
}
```

My elasticsearch server is up and running with some documents in the Index "domainnumber" as well. Each document in the index has 3 more fields in addition to the domain number, which I want the query to return. Once the response is available I would like to render this on the browser. All the examples I have seen online are only about  hardcoding the search value. What's the easiest and quickest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

here there are 2 examples:

1.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Domain Number": "201710283fc113afa731459285b55d94bb8ddf02"
    }
  }
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://192.168.X.XXX:9200/domainnumber/_search");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.send(data);
```

2

```
var settings = {
  "url": "http://192.168.X.XXX:9200/domainnumber/_search",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\r\n\"query\" : {\r\n   \"match\": {\r\n     \"Domain Number\":\"201710283fc113afa731459285b55d94bb8ddf02\"\r\n         }\r\n       }\r\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```